# pandas replace column values except one

Tags: python, pandas

Original dataframe:

```
    DocID   DocURL                       DocName    SiteURL LibraryURL
0   29806   path/to/doc/docname1.doc    docname1    web/url lib/url
1   29807   path/to/doc/docname2.doc    docname2    web/url lib/url
```

New dataframe:

```
    DocURL                   DocName    SiteURL LibraryURL
0   path/to/doc/newname.doc  newname    web/url lib/url
```

I want to replace the row with DocID == 29806 with this new row.

I have tried doing it by using following code without success:

```
df.loc[:, df.columns != 'DocID'].loc[row_index] = new_df.iloc[0]
```

And this:

```
df.loc[row_index][1:] = new_df.iloc[0]
```

For the first one I don't get any error or warning, for the next one I get:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Now, I want / need the row in the original dataframe to be replaced with the row of the new dataframe, but I need the DocID to be kept the same.
I also need the result to be stored in the original dataframe.

Comment: It looks like the problem comes from trying to replace an entire row at once, can you try replacing the individual objects?

Comment: I'd rather replace the whole row at once, since there are many more attributes in the dataframe. I used a simplified representation of the real dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_df["DocID"] = [29806]

old_df.set_index("DocID")
new_df.set_index("DocID")

old_df.update(new_df)
```

Your best bet is to add a `DocID` column to your new dataframe and populate it with the DocIDs from the old dataframe you'd like to update. Then, set `DocID` to be the index. Finally, calling `.update` defaults to aligning on indices, and the behavior is fully controlled.

Comment: Simplest approach without me having to manually identify all the columns.
Thanks. However, it should be new_df['DocID'] = 29806, not [29806]

Comment: @aze45sq6d setting `new_df['DocID'] = 29806` will result in setting 29806 as the value in the entire `DocID` column in `new_df`. If `new_df` has more than a single row and you want different `DocID`s per row, you'll need to pass a list.

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to create a list of columns to replace and then use `to_numpy` to avoid any alignment issue like:

```
cols_replace = ['DocURL','DocName','SiteURL','LibraryURL']
df.loc[row_index, cols_replace] = new_df.loc[0, cols_replace].to_numpy()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `df.update()` to get what you need.

**Code:**

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({'DocID':[29806,29807],'DocURL':['path/to/doc/docname1.doc','path/to/doc/docname2.doc'],
                'DocName':['docname1','docname2'],'SiteURL':['web/url','web/url'],
                'LibraryURL':['lib/url','lib/url']})

df2=pd.DataFrame({'DocURL':['path/to/doc/newname.doc'],
                'DocName':['newname'],'SiteURL':['web/url'],
                'LibraryURL':['lib/url']})

df.update(df2)
```

**Output:**

```py
    DocID   DocURL                   DocName       SiteURL  LibraryURL
0   29806   path/to/doc/newname.doc  newname       web/url  lib/url
1   29807   path/to/doc/docname2.doc docname2      web/url  lib/url
```

`df.update()` in this case will update your original values in `df` with the new values in `df2`. The update will be done based on index. So make sure the index numbers in `df2` matches those in `df`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
df.loc[df['DocID'] == '29806', ['DocURL', 'DocName', 'SiteURL', 'LibraryURL']] = dfNew.iloc[0]['DocURL', 'DocName', 'SiteURL', 'LibraryURL']
```